# How to avoid Rx.Subject in a function constructor but still allow early subscribers

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mutable, rxjs

I'm using object-oriented JavaScript with rxjs and am looking for a "nice" solution / best practice of how to initialize a member variable, that later should be an observable sequence, in the constructor function.

What I do now:

```
var myObject = function() {
    this.observableSequence = new Rx.Subject();
};

myObject.prototype.connect = function(somePromise) {
    var self = this;
    somePromise.done(function(anotherSequence) {
        anotherSequence.forEach(function(element) {
            self.observableSequence.onNext(element);
        });
    });
};
```

In the above example (which works as it is), I basically wait for an external promise (passed by a library consumer that is out of my control) to resolve and then start piping elements from one observable sequence into another sequence.

I think I am doing something wrong here because of the much overhead code. The only reason I used the `Rx.Subject` is to allow other external subscribers to subscribe to the `observableSequence` prior the completion of the promise. But for my API consumers, I want the details of the .connect() method to be hidden. The consumer shoud just see the `observableSequence` member and be able to subscribe at any time to it.

I'd rather have a solution without the `Rx.Subject` (as some suggest Rx.Subject shouldn't be used as it is a mutable) and am also wondering if there is a better way to perform the 'piping' between the to observable sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative without Rx.Subject() would have `this.observableSequence` described entirely inside the constructor, but you would need a reference to the future `somePromise`, say `proxyToSomePromise`. It's useful to have `proxyToSomePromise` be an observable so it can be used to calculate `this.observableSequence`. So essentially we come back to having the same problem: `proxyToSomePromise` should be an Rx.Subject() since `somePromise` isn't yet available.

I can't see how you can avoid Subject. In most cases you can use pure observables, but Subjects have their use case, they are necessary. They are a core piece of [Cycle.js](https://github.com/staltz/cycle/blob/master/src/data-flow-node.js#L9-L20) too. Its mutability isn't a problem if you encapsulate the subject from the outside world, i.e., use [`asObservable()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/asobservable.md).